# Issues with Django and pytz

Tags: django, timezone, pytz

I've followed the time zone documentation on the Django site with no luck. My issue is that I have a select box on my template that should be populated with common timezones provided by pytz, but, for whatever reason it's empty.

My end goal is to allow users to select their own time zone.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

**view.py:**

```
def set_timezone(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        request.session['django_timezone'] = pytz.timezone(request.POST['timezone'])
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'n2w/leads.html', {'timezones': pytz.common_timezones})
```

**leads.html:**

```
            {% load tz %}
            {{ datetime }}
            <form action="" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="timezone">Time zone:</label>
                <select name="timezone">
                    {% for tz in timezones %}
                        <option value="{{ tz }}"{% if tz == TIME_ZONE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ tz }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
                <input type="submit" value="Set" />
            </form>
```

**settings.py:**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.timezone.TimeZoneMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        )

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'registration',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'n2w',
    'n2api',
    'dajaxice',
    'pytz',
)
```

**middleware class (timezone.py):**

```
from django.utils import timezone

class TimeZoneMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        tz = request.session.get('django_timezone')
        if tz:
            timezone.activate(tz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading my Python installation from 2.7.1 -> 2.7.3, I was able to import pytz flawlessly. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably raising a NameError or something. Try importing pytz:

from pytz import common_timezones

...

...

return render(request, 'n2w/leads.html', {'timezones': common_timezones})

Comment: you will need to provide more debug on that buddy, a server side change to actually send the list certainly couldn't be the actual reason your browser crashed.

Comment: try this in a python terminal for example so you can see the output:

>>> pytz.common_timezones
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pytz' is not defined

now try:

>>> from pytz import common_timezones
>>> common_timezones
here you will see the terminal print the list of common timezones.

if this changed caused a browser crash then you have error s elsewhere in the code.

one potential problem area is request.POST['var']

try using request.POST.get('var')

more debug output will help me help you further

Comment: Yes! Cool, so now we know that your system for some reason is unable to import pytz. What version of python are you running?